# Triggering carousel next / carousel previous in twitter bootstrap from colorbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, colorbox, carousel

I'd like colorbox's previous/next control buttons to change the current slide in a twitter bootstrap carousel. Also, as my page has multiple carousels, I want to be able to target the correct carousel.

Each colorbox has a gallery, and each carousel has a unique id, so, in my mind, something like `$('.colorbox #gallery1')` on `$(next)` `$('#carousel1').('next')` seems right, but I don't know which colorbox event I can trigger this from, and the correct js to do so.

Comment: Post code buddy. Read FAQ and About us to learn more about posting ... helps to get answers here on SO. Thanks and welcome to community

Comment: The best I can do is offer a link to the page I'm working on. Colorbox doesn't seem to work inside jsfiddle. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Absolutely buddy ,.. anything that help us see the main issue ... helps resolve

Comment: OK, the page I'm working on is [link](www.livedrummer.co.uk/test/bootstrap/gear.php). I've not tried adding anything to tie the next/previous functions on there yet. I've also got a strange issue with the pagination dots, but I've asked about that on the bootstrap group.